# SWT: notify a composite that it has a new child

Tags: java, swt

How to notify a `Composite` if a new child control has been created?

The reason: by default, for the `StackLayout` no child is shown. I want to ensure that the first control which is added to our `StackLayoutComposite` (which is a `Composite` with set `StackLayout` and a few other helper methods) is shown by default. Currently, I solved it by overriding `StackLayout`'s `layout` method, but this looks ugly in my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to re-layout the parent `Composite` based on the new child and any associated layout data, just use `composite.layout(true);`...

If you want to be notified by the parent that the widget hierarchy has been changed, then you're out of luck... The closest you can get, is to add a SWT filter to the display and wait for a `SWT.Resize` event for a previously unknown child... I have done this is a project, but I have to admit that the code gets a bit ugly as you have to monitor for disposal as well...