# How to be notified that a composite's child received/lost focus?

Tags: java, events, focus, swt, hierarchy

I have an SWT `Composite` that I need to pass to some other code which will add children to it at will. Is there any way to be notified that a child of the composite received and lost focus?

Just to make sure it's clear, I cannot add listeners to each child, because I'm not in charge of creating those controls. A child could be added at any time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by Favonius, you can hook layout events like `SWT.Resize` to determine when you're being painted and recompute your child hierarchy, adding listeners as appropriate.  Another option is simply to listen for **all** focus events and only pay attention to those that are for controls that you're interested in.

`Display`s have **filters** which, like listeners, are notified of events, however filters differ in that they are run before listeners, they have the opportunity to cancel events, and they are notified for all of a type of event on the entire `Display`.

You could thus use a `Filter` to examine all focus events and determine if it's one that you're interested in.  For example:

```
public class MyControl extends Composite
{
    private final Listener focusListener;

    public MyControl(final Composite parent, final int style)
    {
        /* initialize the control... */

        focusListener = new Listener()
        {
            public void handleEvent(Event event)
            {
                if (!(event.widget instanceof Control))
                {
                    return;
                }

                boolean isOurChild = false;
                for (Control c = (Control) event.widget; c != null; c = c.getParent())
                {
                    if (c == container)
                    {
                        isOurChild = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (isOurChild)
                {
                    System.out.println("Our child is " + (event.type == SWT.FocusIn ? "focused" : "unfocused"));
                }
            }
        };

        getDisplay().addFilter(SWT.FocusIn, focusListener);
        getDisplay().addFilter(SWT.FocusOut, focusListener);

        addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener()
        {
            public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e)
            {
                getDisplay().removeFilter(SWT.FocusIn, focusListener);
                getDisplay().removeFilter(SWT.FocusOut, focusListener);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Do note the [javadoc for `Display`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html)'s warnings about using filters:

> They should generally be avoided for performance, debugging and code maintenance reasons.

Obviously you're looking at performance trade-offs in either solution - depending on what type of application you're delivering and your users' workflow, it may make more sense to add focus listeners when you resize, or it may make more sense to simply listen to all focus events and ignore the ones you're not interested in.

Comment: Thanks! Both your answer and the one by Favonius would solve the problem. Yours seems better for my particular application, since it will have N tab folders and each tab in each folder will have a composite as its control. The folder has an event for when a tab is selected, but not when focus enters the tab, which is something I might need to know. Opting for either approach would mean listening to all focus events, because all controls that can receive focus will be inside those tab folders. That's why I chose your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked this link: [SWT: notify a composite that it has a new child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452856/swt-notify-a-composite-that-it-has-a-new-child)

As per the proposed solution in the above link the only possible solution is to use the `resize` event. Based on that see the following code, which adds a focus listener on all the immediate child nodes. Though the solution itself is not very elegant.

### Test Code

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class SWTApplication 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SWTApplication().initSystem("Children Notification");
    }

    private Display display;
    private Shell shell;

    public void initSystem(String windowName)
    {
        display = new Display();
        shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText(windowName);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, true));
        shell.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        final TestFocusListener listener = new TestFocusListener();

        shell.addControlListener(new ControlListener() {
            public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() instanceof Shell)
                {
                    Shell s = (Shell)e.getSource();
                    Control[] children = s.getChildren();
                    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) 
                    {
                        Control c = children[i];
                        c.removeFocusListener(listener);
                        c.addFocusListener(listener);
                    }
                }
            }
            public void controlMoved(ControlEvent e) {
            }
        });


        createControls();

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }

        display.dispose();
    }

    private void createControls() 
    {
        String[] name = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
        {
            Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
            button.setText(name[i] + " button");
            button.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
            shell.setSize(shell.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
        }
    }

    class TestFocusListener implements FocusListener
    {
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            Object src = e.getSource();
            if(src instanceof Button)
            {
                System.out.println("Focus gained: " + ((Button)src).getText());
            }

        }
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            Object src = e.getSource();
            if(src instanceof Button)
            {
                System.out.println("Focus lost: " + ((Button)src).getText());
            }
        }
    }

}
```