# Java SWT - listen if new children are added to the Composite?

Tags: java, events, user-interface, swt

I have a `Composite`.
In SWT the children are added, by children, no by parents:

```
Composite parent = new Composite(shell, SWT.none);
Composite child = new Composite(parent, SWT.none);
```

That means, that inside of the parent I do not know, in which way and when the children are added to their parents.

**QUESTION:**

Inside of the parent I need to know, when new children are added to the parent. 
Is there any way to register an `onChildAddListener` or any `add()` method to override?

Comment: Have to assign "Active" state to the first item, which is added. For my apps own logic.

Comment: Then the answers in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517634/how-to-be-notified-that-a-composites-child-received-lost-focus) seem to be the only way to achieve this. Basically, listen to `SWT.Resize` events...

Comment: BTW: If you add the Components yourself, why don't you just set the first one to "Active" manually?

Comment: Because it will be one more thing to think of, 1 more error source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to add custom `MyComposite` and create custom `ChildEvent` as well as `ChildEventListener` interface. `MyComposite` is capable of registering listeners of `ChildEvent` and fire this event when a child `Composite` is created.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.TypedEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.internal.SWTEventListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

/*
 * This example demonstrates the minimum amount of code required
 * to open an SWT Shell and process the events.
 */
public class HelloWorld1 {

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Display display = new Display ();
    Shell shell = new HelloWorld1 ().open (display);
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    display.dispose ();
}

public Shell open (Display display) {
    Shell shell = new Shell (display);
    MyComposite parent = new MyComposite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    parent.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void add(ChildEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Child added.");

        }
    });
    MyComposite child = new MyComposite(parent, SWT.NONE);

//  shell.open ();
    return shell;
}
}

class MyComposite extends Composite {

    ChildEventListener[] childEventListeners = new ChildEventListener[0];

    public MyComposite(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        if (parent instanceof MyComposite){
            ((MyComposite)parent).fireChildEvent(new ChildEvent(this));
        }
    }
    public void addChildEventListener (ChildEventListener listener) {
        checkWidget();
        if (listener == null) SWT.error (SWT.ERROR_NULL_ARGUMENT);
        ChildEventListener[] newChildEventListeners = new ChildEventListener[childEventListeners.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(childEventListeners, 0, newChildEventListeners, 0, childEventListeners.length);
        childEventListeners = newChildEventListeners;
        childEventListeners[childEventListeners.length - 1] = listener;
    }
    public void removeChildEventListener (ChildEventListener listener) {
        if (childEventListeners.length == 0) return;
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < childEventListeners.length; i++) {
            if (listener == childEventListeners[i]){
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (index == -1) return;
        if (childEventListeners.length == 1) {
            childEventListeners = new ChildEventListener[0];
            return;
        }
        ChildEventListener[] newChildEventListeners = new ChildEventListener[childEventListeners.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy (childEventListeners, 0, newChildEventListeners, 0, index);
        System.arraycopy (childEventListeners, index + 1, newChildEventListeners, index, childEventListeners.length - index - 1);
        childEventListeners = newChildEventListeners;
    }
    public void fireChildEvent(ChildEvent event){
        for (int i = 0; i < childEventListeners.length; i++) {
            childEventListeners[i].add (event);
        }

    }
}

interface ChildEventListener extends SWTEventListener {
    public void add(ChildEvent e);
}

class ChildEvent extends TypedEvent {

    public ChildEvent(Widget widget) {
        super(widget);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm from one year later. And I wanna thank you! This was helpful.

Comment: @Roman C: This solution seems pretty useless to me. Because it can only notify parents if `MyComposite` objects are added to other `MyComposite`s, not if any standard control is added. I really think you should mention this limitation in the solution text.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose for which I wanted to know about child addition - is for layoing out the children
(adding `LayoutData` e.g. `GridData`) when the child is added to a child, which is layed out with a particular Layout (e.g. `GridLayout`).

Since it is not possible to layout children on addition - check their layout on every widget resize:

```
    /*
     * To make the forms fill the group - laying out the children is necessary.
     * Unfortunately it is not possible to listen for children addition, in order to layout the children addition automatically.
     * This means that the user will have to remember  to layout the children, which is a nogo.
     * 
     * Solution: 
     * istead of adding right layout on child addition -  check if there are new children every time the widget is resized.
     * if a widget without layoutData is found (new child not layed out) - add a layout
     */
    this.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
            layoutChildren();
        }
    });
}
private void layoutChildren(){
    for(Control child:getChildren()){
        if(child.getLayoutData() == null){
            child.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1)); 
        }
    }
}

public void addToGroup(Composite child){
    child.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
}
```